# Decrease the execution time

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query in Toad. I want to generate the numbers do not exist in tale2. The result is what I expect, but it takes more than two hours. Do you have any suggestion to optimize?

```
`declare cursor Range is

select lower_b,uper_b,brnch_Cd from temp_bound;

diff number;

begin

for i in Range 

loop

 diff= uper_b-lower_b;

 for j in 1..diff  

 loop

 insert into table1 select /*+Parallel*/ i.lower_b+j,i.brnch_cd from 

dual where (select count(*)   from table2 where 

table2.col2=i.lower_b+j)=0;

 end loop

end loop

end
```

I would like to reduce the execution time

Comment: "Do you have any suggestion to optimize?" - don't use a cursor

Answer (score 1):

Code you posted is invalid because

- you used `=` instead of `:=`
- didn't reference cursor variable
- miss closing semi-colons

---

Sample tables and data:

```
SQL> select * from temp_bound;

   LOWER_B     UPER_B   BRNCH_CD
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          5        100
         8         10        200

SQL> select * from table2;

      COL2
----------
         3           --> which means that MISSING values are
         8           --> 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10

SQL> desc table1;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 VAL                                                NUMBER
 BRNCH_CD                                           NUMBER

SQL>
```

---

**Your code**, fixed (so that it actually runs and does *something*):

```
SQL> declare
  2    cursor Range is
  3      select lower_b,uper_b,brnch_Cd from temp_bound;
  4    diff number;
  5  begin
  6    for i in Range
  7    loop
  8      diff:= i.uper_b-i.lower_b;
  9      for j in 1..diff
 10      loop
 11        insert into table1
 12          select /*+Parallel*/ i.lower_b+j,i.brnch_cd
 13          from dual where (select count(*) from table2
 14                           where table2.col2=i.lower_b+j)=0;
 15      end loop;
 16    end loop;
 17  end;
 18  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from table1;

       VAL   BRNCH_CD
---------- ----------
         2        100
         4        100
         5        100
         9        200
        10        200

SQL>
```

As you can see result isn't complete; `1` is mssing.

---

**Alternatively**, avoid slow row-by-row processing and skip PL/SQL altogether.

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> insert into table1 (val, brnch_cd)
  2  with temp as
  3    (select lower_b + column_value - 1 as val, brnch_cd
  4     from temp_bound cross join
  5       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  6                           connect by level <= uper_b - lower_b + 1
  7                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
  8    )
  9  select a.val, a.brnch_cd
 10  from temp a
 11  where not exists (select null
 12                    from table2 b
 13                    where b.col2 = a.val
 14                   );

6 rows created.
```

Result is now complete and should perform better than your attempt.

```
SQL> select * From table1;

       VAL   BRNCH_CD
---------- ----------
         1        100
         2        100
         4        100
         5        100
         9        200
        10        200

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL:

```
insert into table1 select /*+Parallel*/ i.lower_b+j,i.brnch_cd from 
dual where (select count(*)   from table2 where 
table2.col2=i.lower_b+j)=0;
```

First, see Littlefoot's answer on not using PL/SQL at all. If you must use PL/SQL and looping, then **remove the parallel hint**. Parallelism will destroy your performance if you're going after a tiny fraction of rows in a loop like this. The overhead to start up those PX slaves just isn't worth it.

Secondly, the way you have written your subquery (`COUNT(*) = 0`) won't allow Oracle to use indexes on table2. **Rewrite this** to:

```
insert into table1 select i.lower_b+j,i.brnch_cd from 
dual where not exists (select * from table2 where 
table2.col2=i.lower_b+j)
```

And then **index table2.col2**.

Also, `dual` tends to get overused and is unnecessary here. Use PL/SQL for your conditional logic. And while we're at it, let's use a variable so we don't repeat our arithmetic logic in two places:

```
DECLARE
  var_exists integer;
  var_my_new_value number;
  . . [other stuff]. .
BEGIN
  . . [other stuff]. .

  var_my_new_value := i.lower_b+j;

  select count(*) 
    into var_exists
    from table2 
   where col2=var_my_new_value;

  IF var_exists = 0
  THEN
    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (var_my_new_value,i.brnch_cd);
  END IF;
END;
```